# How do I keep a selected drop-down option in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have made a **[blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0)** in Laravel 8.

The articles support comments and the comments need to be approved by an admin before being published.

I have added a select-box to filter comments by status or just display them all:

```
<form class="d-flex align-items-center" method="get" action="{{ route('dashboard.comments')}}">
  <label for="commentsFilter" class="form-label mb-0 me-1">Filter</label>
  <select class="form-select" id="commentsFilter" name="filter" onchange="this.form.submit()">
     @foreach ($filters as $filter)
       <option value="{{ $filter->value }}" {{ $active_filter == $filter->value ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $filter->label }}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
</form>
```

In the CommentController controller, I have:

```
class CommentController extends Controller
{

  public function index(Request $request)
  {
    // Total number of comments
    $comments_count =  Comment::count();

    // Total number of unapproved comments
    $unapproved_comments_count = Comment::where('approved', 0)->count();

    // Comments per page
    $per_page = 10;

    // Comments filters
    $filters = $filter = [
      (object)[
        'value' => 'all',
        'label' => 'All comments'
      ],
      (object)[
        'value' => 0,
        'label' => 'Unapproved'
      ],
      (object)[
        'value' => 1,
        'label' => 'Approved'
      ]
    ];

    // Get active filter from URL
     $active_filter = $request->query('filter');
   

    // Comments (with filter)
    $filter = $request->input('filter');

    $comments = Comment::orderBy('id', 'desc')
      ->when($filter !== 'all', function ($query) use ($filter) {
        return $query->where('approved', $filter);
      }, function ($query) {
        return $query->where('approved', 1)->orWhere('approved', 0);
      })
      ->paginate($per_page)->onEachSide(1);

    return view(
      'dashboard/article-comments',
        [
          'per_page' => $per_page,
          'current_page' => $comments->currentPage(),
          'comments' => $comments,
          'comments_count' => $comments_count,
          'unapproved_comments_count' => $unapproved_comments_count,
          'filters' => $filters,
          'active_filter' => $active_filter,
        ]
      );
  }
}
```

#### The problem

When I choose to see all the comments (from the `<select>` element), the `<option value="all">All comments</option>` does **not stay selected**, while the other 2 options **do** remain selected when chosen).

Replacing `$filter = $request->input('filter')` with:

```
// Get active filter from URL
if (isset($active_filter) && !is_null($active_filter)) {
     $active_filter = $request->query('filter');
} else {
     $active_filter = 'all';
}
```

also fails.

How can I keep the "All comments" option selected when the URL is `dashboard/comments?filter=all`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can explicitly check for the `all` value in the request and default to `all` when no specific filter is applied.

```
$active_filter = $request->query('filter', 'all');

// Ensure $active_filter is valid, otherwise default to 'all'
if (!in_array($active_filter, ['all', '0', '1'])) {
  $active_filter = 'all';
}

$comments = Comment::orderBy('id', 'desc')
  ->when($active_filter !== 'all', function ($query) use ($active_filter) {
    return $query->where('approved', $active_filter);
  })
  ->paginate($per_page)->onEachSide(1);
```

`$active_filter` is set to `all` both when the filter is not specified in the URL and when `all` is explicitly chosen. This should keep the `All comments` option selected.

Debug your selectbox and confirm the values also explicitly cast both sides of the comparison to strings.

```
@foreach ($filters as $filter)
    @php
        var_dump($active_filter, $filter->value);
    @endphp
    <option value="{{ $filter->value }}" {{ (string)$active_filter === (string)$filter->value ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $filter->label }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I did the above and: 1) on the route `/dashboard/comments`, the selected option is `<option value="0" selected="">Unapproved</option>`. 2) When I select "All comments", the same happens. Maybe the is something wrong with the Blade file?

Comment: May be you have string comparsion issue, try to debug and then see, upading the answer

Comment: It was a string comparison issue it seems.